# Executar função com ENTER no EditText

Tags: java, android

Preciso executar uma função com o "Enter" do teclado no `EditText`.

*Não funcionaram:*

`android:maxLines="1"`: ele pula campos

`android:imeOptions="actionNext"`: ele executa com o botão "próximo" do teclado virtual

`setOnKeyListener` com `keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`: bloqueia o EditText e não deixa inserir nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funcionando:

```
this.edt = findViewById(R.id.editText);

this.edt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        metodo();
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Lista completa das keys: [Documento oficial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)