# Manter o foco no edittext depois de apertar Enter

Tags: android, edittext

Eu tenho um leitor de código de barras que faz a ação de colocar o texto no edittext e apertar enter automáticamente, implementei a função ao fazer a leitura mas gostaria que o foco no edittext continuasse.
Meu código :

```
final EditText codBarras = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.codigoBarras);
        codBarras.requestFocus();

        codBarras.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on key press
                    SQLiteDatabase dbr = banco.getReadableDatabase();
                    Cursor cursor = dbr.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM produto WHERE codigo_barra = '"+codBarras.getText().toString()+"'", null);
                    if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        addItens(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                    }
                    codBarras.setText("");
                    codBarras.requestFocus();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Mesmo com o requestFocus o foco do edittext muda.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, mas tenho 2 tópicos separados: [Autofoco em EditText não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/autofoco-em-edittext-n%c3%a3o-funciona) e [Executar função com ENTER no EditText](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291691/executar-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-com-enter-no-edittext)

Comment: Mano se eu conseguir posto a resposta na sua pergunta :D

Comment: Nós estamos procurando a mesma solução. Agora que entendi o que você quer ! rs

Comment: Publiquei a resposta lá